# Outlook / Excel integration ?

Tags: excel

I have the following problem.  I use MSword mail merge to send emails.  I regularly send out 100-500 emails (not spam, singular requests).  I keep my email addresses in a single MSexcel sheet.  Many of the email addresses are broken, and most replies are negative.  Many of the emails responses come within the first 30 minutes of sending the email.  After I get a response, I need to mark the response on the excel list.  This process can be time consuming.  Thus, the problem.  Now, the question.

Is there a way to make my computer check the subject line of my emails for a specified string, and if it contains that string, then it copies the email address from that email, either in the body of the email, or in the sender field, and then moves to a specified excel sheet, searches for the email address in the excel sheet, and then marks the email address in the excel sheet.

Very happy for anyone that can point me in the right direction.  I have absolutely no programming experience. I have used computers my entire life, but mostly to send and receive emails, or browse the internet.

Comment: This isn't really an 'on-topic' question for this site as it has nothing to do with Database Administration. However, I'm guessing you have an Exchange Server (as you're using Outlook), so one method would be a C#.Net Application that uses Exchange Web Services to read the emails and writes to an Excel file

Answer (score 0):

You can use this directly from Excel, it's a bit overkill for what you want but you can remove fields if you don't need them:

```
 '*********************************************************************************************
 ' All code is supplied under the Creative Commons License (CC). Code samples provided by
 ' Wilde XL Solutions are strictly for non-commerical use only and provided for the purpose
 ' learning and study. If you would like to seek permission to use this code in any way other
 ' than specified in this license agreement, please email cc@wxls.co.uk.
 '
 ' A copy of the general creative commons (CC) license can be found at:
 ' http://tinyurl.com/WXLSCCinfo
 '*********************************************************************************************

Sub getMail()

      ' This sub is designed to be used with a blank worksheet. It will create the header
      ' fields as required, and continue to populate the email data below the relevant header.

      ' Declare required variables
      '-------------------------------------------------------------
     Dim olApp As Object
     Dim olFolder As Object
     Dim olMailItem As Object

     Dim strTo As String
     Dim strFrom As String
     Dim dateSent As Variant
     Dim dateReceived As Variant
     Dim strSubject As String
     Dim strBody As String

     Dim loopControl As Variant
     Dim mailCount As Long
     Dim totalItems As Long
      '-------------------------------------------------------------

      'Turn off screen updating
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      'Setup headers for information
     Range("A1:F1").Value = Array("To", "From", "Subject", "Body", "Sent (from Sender)", "Received (by Recipient)")

      'Format columns E and F to
     Columns("E:F").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS"

      'Create instance of Outlook
     Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

      'Select folder to extract mail from
     Set olFolder = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder

      'Get count of mail items
     totalItems = olFolder.items.Count
     mailCount = 0

      'Loop through mail items in folder
     For Each loopControl In olFolder.items

          'If loopControl is a mail item then continue
         If TypeName(loopControl) = "MailItem" Then

              'Increase mailCount
             mailCount = mailCount + 1

              'Inform user of item count in status bar
             Application.StatusBar = "Reading email no. " & mailCount & " of " & totalItems

              'Get mail item
             Set olMailItem = loopControl

              'Get Details
             With olMailItem
                 strTo = .To
                  'If strTo begins with "=" then place an apostrophe in front to denote text format
                 If Left(strTo, 1) = "=" Then strTo = "'" & strTo
                 strFrom = .Sender
                  'If sender displays name only, show name followed by email address e.g.(Bloggs, Joe < j.bloggs@mail.com >)
                 If InStr(1, strFrom, "@") < 1 Then strFrom = strFrom & " - < " & .SenderEmailAddress & " >"
                 dateSent = .SentOn
                 dateReceived = .ReceivedTime
                 strSubject = .Subject
                 strBody = .Body
             End With

              'Place information into spreadsheet
              'import information starting from last blank row in column A
             With Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0)
                 .Value = strTo
                 .Offset(1, 1).Value = strFrom
                 .Offset(2, 2).Value = strSubject

                  'Check for previous replies by looking for "From:" in the body text
                  'Check for the word "From:"
                 If InStr(0, strBody, "From:") > 0 Then
                      'If exists, copy start of email body, up to the position of "From:"
                     .Offset(1, 1).Value = Mid(strBody, 1, InStr(1, strBody, "From:") - 1)
                 Else
                      'If doesn't exist, copy entire mail body
                     .Offset(3, 3).Value = strBody
                 End If

                 .Offset(4, 4).Value = dateSent
                 .Offset(5, 5).Value = dateReceived

             End With

              'Release item from memory
             Set olMailItem = Nothing

         End If

          'Next Item
     Next loopControl

      'Release items from memory
     Set olFolder = Nothing
     Set olApp = Nothing

      'Resume screen updating
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      'reset status bar
     Application.StatusBar = False

      'Inform user that code has finished
     MsgBox mailCount & " messages copied successfully.", vbInformation, "Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure where I would run this script.  Would I run this script in excel?

Comment: Yes, place it in a standard Module in an Excel workbook and run it from there, it does the rest itself.

Comment: Cool.  Ok, I got the visual basic editor, and the module open.  Now, I need to figure out the next steps in the process.  By the way, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Press Alt + F11 to open VBE, then hold down the Alt key and press I then M. This will open a module, then paste that code into it. Then go back to Excel, press Alt + F8 and select the getMail macro, then press "Run"

Comment: Note that this is just a starting point, you will need to adapt this code for your specific needs

Comment: You won't find anything about modifying this code specifically (I know, because I wrote it) - you will need to learn basic VBA programming. Which is simply a Google search, it's a bit too vague a question for this particular site but there are plenty of free Excel/VBA forums online that can help :)